# Mongo Document update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, object, mongoose

I have below data:

```json
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "6459f1020162e7e3649729c9"
        },
        "user_id": {
            "$oid": "644fd02b7add0a888e2e8e84"
        },
        "creditTotal": 500,
        "debitTotal": 0,
        "creditDebitTotal": 500,
        "userWallet": [
            {
                "userName": "hhjj",
                "mobileNumber": "6666699888",
                "sumTotal": 500,
                "debit": {
                    "totalDebit": 0,
                    "transactions": []
                },
                "credit": {
                    "totalCredit": 500,
                    "transactions": [
                        {
                            "amount": 500,
                            "date": "2023-05-17",
                            "description": "didi",
                            "_id": {
                                "$oid": "64644941a6a3a7abdbf90316"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "6462f70a2ff97a1eac2290a8"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "6459f1020162e7e3649729ce"
        },
        "user_id": {
            "$oid": "6459ecf2dcb04e1d845bb6f2"
        },
        "creditTotal": 2500,
        "debitTotal": 1000,
        "creditDebitTotal": 1500,
        "userWallet": [
            {
                "userName": "h",
                "mobileNumber": "22222222222",
                "sumTotal": 1500,
                "debit": {
                    "totalDebit": 1000,
                    "transactions": [
                        {
                            "amount": 1000,
                            "date": "2023-05-16",
                            "description": "rt",
                            "_id": {
                                "$oid": "64635ad2a6a3a7abdbf8f4b1"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "credit": {
                    "totalCredit": 2500,
                    "transactions": [
                        {
                            "amount": 500,
                            "date": "2023-05-16",
                            "description": "ft",
                            "_id": {
                                "$oid": "646359e3a6a3a7abdbf8f4ac"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "amount": 2000,
                            "date": "2023-05-16",
                            "description": "rt",
                            "_id": {
                                "$oid": "64635ba6a6a3a7abdbf8f4c7"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "64630eb92ff97a1eac229517"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to update an element in transaction with the element id as input.

Input:

```json
{
    "user_id": "6459ecf2dcb04e1d845bb6f2", // user_id for level 1 match
    "walletId": "64630eb92ff97a1eac229517", // for userWallet object match
    "transId": "646359e3a6a3a7abdbf8f4ac", // transaction array object match
    "amount": "5000", // updated amount
    "type": "Credit" // userWallet credit or debit category check
}
```

I want to update object with `user_id` == `"644fd02b7add0a888e2e8e84"` as below:

```json
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6459f1020162e7e3649729ce"
    },
    "user_id": {
        "$oid": "6459ecf2dcb04e1d845bb6f2"
    },
    "creditTotal": 7000,
    "debitTotal": 1000,
    "creditDebitTotal": 6000,
    "userWallet": [
        {
            "userName": "h",
            "mobileNumber": "22222222222",
            "sumTotal": 6000,
            "debit": {
                "totalDebit": 1000,
                "transactions": [
                    {
                        "amount": 1000,
                        "date": "2023-05-16",
                        "description": "rt",
                        "_id": {
                            "$oid": "64635ad2a6a3a7abdbf8f4b1"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "credit": {
                "totalCredit": 7000,
                "transactions": [
                    {
                        "amount": 5000,
                        "date": "2023-05-16",
                        "description": "ft",
                        "_id": {
                            "$oid": "646359e3a6a3a7abdbf8f4ac"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "amount": 2000,
                        "date": "2023-05-16",
                        "description": "rt",
                        "_id": {
                            "$oid": "64635ba6a6a3a7abdbf8f4c7"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "64630eb92ff97a1eac229517"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried multiple ways but could not reach to the level 2 filter.

```
const filter = {
            "user_id": userId,
            "userWallet._id": id,
            "userWallet.credit.transactions._id": transId
        };

        const update = {
            $set: {
               "userWallet.$.credit.transactions.$[transaction].amount": amount,
            }
        };

        const arrayFilters = [
            { "transaction._id": transId }
        ];

        const updateOptions = {
            returnOriginal: false
        };

        var updatedDocument = await mongoose.connection.collections.wallets.collection.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, { arrayFilters, ...updateOptions });
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`"arrayFilters"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)?

Comment: Yes, I have tried arrayFilters but didn't get desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Tty this:

const arrayFilters = [
{ "transaction._id": transId,
"user_id": userId
}
];

array of filter documents that determine which array elements to modify for an update operation on an array field.https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/

Comment: Returns:

{
    "status": false,
    "error": "Error parsing array filter :: caused by :: Expected a single top-level field name, found 'transaction' and 'user_id'"
}

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it using two `"arrayFilters"`.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "user_id": {"$oid": "6459ecf2dcb04e1d845bb6f2"},
  "userWallet._id": {"$oid": "64630eb92ff97a1eac229517"},
  "userWallet.credit.transactions._id": {"$oid": "646359e3a6a3a7abdbf8f4ac"}
},
{
  "$set": {
    "userWallet.$[wId].credit.transactions.$[tId].amount": 5000
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {"wId._id": {"$oid": "64630eb92ff97a1eac229517"}},
    {"tId._id": {"$oid": "646359e3a6a3a7abdbf8f4ac"}}
  ]
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YNCvelgbOaC).